# Prove If $n$ is odd, then any equation $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0=0$ has a root

Tags: calculus

In Michael Spivak' Calculus Theorem 9 of Chapter 7, when the author tries to prove If $n$ is odd, then any equation $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0=0$ has a root, he chooses $x$ satisfying $|x| > 1, 2n|a_{n-1}|,...,2n|a_0|$.

Why did we choose this? What is the idea behind it?

Here is the original proof:

[image: calc]

Comment: Basically the following calculations show the motivation... the idea is to make terms other than $x^n$ to be relatively smaller than $x^n$ in size.

Comment: @Riemann can I choose $|x| >3n|a_{n-k}|$? The choice of $|x|$ may have other options. Am I right?

Comment: Of course you can replace $2$ by $3$ all along. Or you can choose any other epsilon-delta proof that $\lim_{+\infty}p=+\infty$ and $\lim_{-\infty}p=-\infty.$